# Implementing Sharepoint Without the Ribbon

Tags: development, ribbon

Today when I walked into the office I was greeted with a request to position the ribbon at the top of the page in our Sharepoint Intranet branding in such a way that it:-

A. Does not obscure the branding
B. Does not require any white space below its position in order to function

or ideally:-

C. Disable the ribbon completely from users.

My gut feeling is that A. and B. are not feasible/will cause issues as the ribbon has fixed positioning. E.G. http://www.greggalipeau.com/2011/01/28/a-better-enhanced-sharepoint-2010-floating-ribbon/

I've tried doing some research on option C. and am struggling to find any concrete opinion either way in regards to if removing the ribbon is good or bad.
So I am looking for any experiences or guidance on if an intranet Sharepoint implementation without the ribbon control is a good idea or not? what issues should I be aware of? My initial reaction is that it is a bad idea and will cause a plethora of issues.

Thanks in advance for any answers submitted.

Im happy to add any more details if I have left anything out of my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nicholas,

The SharePoint 2010 ribbon is kind of a double-edged sword. I have seen many business users asking for "not having" the ribbon for the sake of branding. Then there were instances when people needed some extended administrative sections in SharePoint sites without the ribbon.

The fact is no matter what you do, without the ribbon there are numerous tasks and activities which will get hampered straight away and finding custom alternatives through some code is just way too costly and impractical to implement.

Although sharepoint gives us the option of doing majority of the work without the ribbon, but there is a damn good reason why Microsoft opted for having a ribbon on SharePoint 2010. This reason primarily constitutes ease of site management and user experience among the others like a unified branding architecture for office 2010 products.

Said so, the ribbon itself can be made hidden for anonymous users generally used as a practice for public facing SharePoint sites.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010customization/thread/9e52de43-7941-4e61-976b-d6bf2f8d926c

Then there are ways to hide the ribbon from users lacking edit level privileges as mentioned here
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zwsong/archive/2010/04/29/how-to-hide-ribbon-from-users-without-edit-page-privilege.aspx

But its imperative that the ribbon stays visible for administrative users if you wish to avoid unnecessary SharePoint 2010 site management troubles.

Comment: this was my initial thought thank you very much for your feedback i would upvote your answer but i lack the relevant stackexchange experience.

Answer (score 1):

To completely remove the ribbon you best create a new masterpage called NoRibbon.master. In this new masterpage add the following code:

```
style="display:none"
```

Find the following code line in the masterpage:

```
<div id="s4-titlerow" class="s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle">
```

and edit it into this:

```
<div id="s4-titlerow" class="s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle" style="display:none">
```

Apply the new masterpage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I was more looking for experiences both pro and con of removing the ribbon, rather than how to remove the ribbon :-)

Comment: woops, my bad! :-)